# Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _view referenced in function _main

Tags: c, linked-list

I keep getting this error.  unresolved external symbol. It occurred when I wrote a function to search my linked list for unique employeeId's. I ran the function at the point where I asked the user to add employee id, when I got the error. I then commented out the code which I taught caused the problem, but I still get the same error. The function in question is `searchListUniqueId(CONT *head, CONT *newEmployee)`. Any help would great-full, also my head node ie listHead is initialized in my header file.

```
 int userChoice = 0;
 void menu();
 void add();
 void printNodes();
 void view();
 void loadFile();
 void sortedEmployeeInsert(CONT**headPtr, CONT *newEmployee);
 void searchListUniqueId(CONT *head, CONT *newEmployee);

void main()
{
   initLinkList();
   loadFile();

do{
    menu();
    switch (userChoice){
    case 1:
        add();
        userChoice = NULL;
        break;
    case 2:
        printNodes();
        userChoice = NULL;
        break;
    case 3:
        view();
        userChoice = NULL;
        break;
    }
} while (userChoice != -1);

printf("\n\n\n");
system("pause");
}

void loadFile(){
    int iCnt = 0;
    CONT *temp;

    temp = (struct contact*)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
temp->next = listHead;

FILE *cfPtr;
if ((cfPtr = fopen(FILENAME, READMODE)) == NULL){
    puts("File could not be opened");
}// close if

while (fscanf(cfPtr, "%d %s %s %s %s %s %f %d %d %d",
    &temp->employeeId,
    temp->firstName,
    temp->lastName,
    temp->employeeAddress,
    temp->email,
    temp->department,
    &temp->annualSalary,
    &temp->doj.day,
    &temp->doj.month,
    &temp->doj.year) == 10){

    temp->next = NULL;
    if (iCnt == 0)
        listHead = initLinkList_new(temp);
    else
        addEmployeeToEnd(listHead, temp);//pass in the listHead and Temp

    temp = (struct contact*)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    ++iCnt;
    }//while
   fclose(cfPtr);
  }
   void add(){
  // create new contact
    CONT *newEmployee;
    newEmployee = (struct contact*)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));

// get data from user

printf("Enter EmployeeId:\n");
scanf("%d", &newEmployee->employeeId);
searchListUniqueId(listHead, newEmployee);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Enter employee first name:\n");
scanf("%s", &newEmployee->firstName);
fflush(stdin);
//makes sure 1st letter of name is upper case
if (islower(newEmployee->firstName[0])){
    newEmployee->firstName[0] = toupper(newEmployee->firstName[0]);
}

printf("Enter employee last name:\n");
scanf("%s", &newEmployee->lastName);
fflush(stdin);
//makes sure 1st letter of name is upper case
if (islower(newEmployee->lastName[0])){
    newEmployee->lastName[0] = toupper(newEmployee->lastName[0]);
}

printf("Enter Adress:\n");
scanf("%s", &newEmployee->employeeAddress);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Enter email:\n");
scanf("%s", &newEmployee->email);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Department name:\n");
scanf("%s", &newEmployee->department);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Anual Salary:\n");
scanf("%f", &newEmployee->annualSalary);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter The Employee's Hire Date:\n");
printf("-------------------------------\n");
printf("Enter The Day First:\n");
scanf("%d", &newEmployee->doj.day);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter The Month Next:\n");
scanf("%d", &newEmployee->doj.month);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter The Year Last:\n");
scanf("%d", &newEmployee->doj.year);
fflush(stdin);

newEmployee->next = NULL;
sortedEmployeeInsert(&listHead, newEmployee);
//return newEmployee;
}
       void searchListUniqueId(CONT *head, CONT *newEmployee)
       {
       CONT *temp;
       temp = (struct contact*)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
       temp = head;
       while (temp != NULL)
         {
           if (temp->employeeId == newEmployee->employeeId)
           {
              printf("\nEmployee ID already exsits.");
              return;
           }
       temp = temp->next;
         }
        printf("\nEmployee ID is  unique.");
}
```

Comment: I don't see any definition of view() here, do you?

Comment: You have a link error.  This means your program contains a call to a function whose definition is not available to it.  The error message even helpfully tells you which function that is, though you have to decode the name just a bit.

Comment: The error message came after I implemented the  void searchListUniqueId(CONT *head, CONT *newEmployee) function. When I got the error I commented out the function and the function call. But i still get the error. So im at a loss as to why?

Comment: Can you elaborate at bit more on what you mean by: contains a call to a function whose definition is not available to it. And though you have to decode the name just a bit

Comment: I just seen it there Sourav Ghosh Thanks. It took me a while but i got there.